# How to run React Vite project correctly in production mode?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using Vite with React, I want to run the project in production mode on a server.
This is the `vite.config.js` :

```
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    loader: "jsx",
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        ".js": "jsx",
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  }
});
```

And in the running pod on the server after deployment, I have this log :

```
Environment:
DEV_MODE=false
NODE_ENV=production
DEBUG_PORT=XXXX
Launching via npm...
> my-project start
> vite
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 2333ms (cache miss)
VITE v4.3 ready in 2303 ms
➜ Local: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
➜ Network: use --host to expose
```

Is it normal to have it running like that? Also on the port 3000? it looks like the log I get in my localhost.

If not, how can I run the project correctly in production mode and what's the right Vite config for it please?

And using `react-react-app`:

```
Environment:
DEV_MODE=false
NODE_ENV=production
DEBUG_PORT=XXXX
Launching via npm...
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm
npm info using node
> @my-app start /opt/app-root/src
> react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /opt/app-root/src/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Comment: For frontend app only, you should not run a server. The only thing you need to do is to build your app and serve it as static files.

Comment: _"I don't have much control of the server"_ - in that case there's not much we can do either. You need to speak to whoever _does_ have control of how it's deployed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to know first if that log is what I should probobaly expect or there's something wrong with my Vite configuration. I want to know people's opinion about this matter.

Comment: If you're just asking _"should I run the dev server in production?"_, then: no, it's the _dev_ server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not the best way, to serve a React app using a dedicated server, but if you insist, you should use a solution with NGINX. First of all, from inspecting your logs, you run `vite` to start your application.

Running just `vite` starts up a development server to serve your application, which is not good for production, https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html#dev-server.

What you do need to do, is first to build your React application to get optimized static resources of your application ready to be served, using `vite build`, https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html#build.

Then you need to use NGINX to serve your build artifacts.

You can use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.17 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
COPY --from=build /app/dist /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

then you need to run in your server:

```bash
docker build -t vite-app .
docker run -p 80:80 vite-app
```

Comment: Ok I understand better now, thank you.

Comment: @Dwix please contact your manager to deploy your frontend application in some cloud solution, AWS::CloudFront and AWS::S3, I believe an organization has the budget. If it just an application for internal usage, have fun with my solution, it is ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'll do that.